# calculate GPA from String array where the elements of array represents credit hours and grade e.g: 3A+,2B+?

Tags: java

I'm a new learn of Java so the question is how to split string element of array as: 3A+ which means 3 hours and have in them A+ , what is the way to take credit alone and grade alone ??
since I create the class student which have these attribute 
Class Student has the following members:
• Four attributes: name, ID, gradList, and GPA.
• gradList attribute represents student grades on all courses; where the first character
represent course credit hour followed by a grade. ( if the first element on gradList is 3A+, it
means student take on a course of three hours A+.)

Comment: Have a look at the methods that `String` provides, especially the `split()` method.

Comment: Can the pattern of string element be changed to something like 3,A+ ?

Comment: I had to look up what "GPA" meant. It has a country-specific definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume *str* is the string containing value 3A+ or 2B+ etc.

This can be split into an array of strings satisfying your conditions,

```
String[] strArr =str.split("(?<=[\\d,]+)(?![\\d,])");
```

Here `str` is split into an array of strings, `strArr` using the regex pattern, `(?<=[\\d,]+)(?![\\d,])`,

which implies selecting an empty character after a digit, and also additional negative look{ahead,behind}s to avoid matching them in the middle(in case credit has more than one digit)

If the string format is something like **3,A+** its much more simpler,

```
String[] strArr =str.split(",");
```

Here `strArr[0]` contains the value of *credit* and `strArr[1]` contains the value of *grade*.
Hope this helps.